# Building solution fails due to missing dll files

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I've been dealing with a plethora of VS issues on my project. I ended up cloning a fresh copy of the repository. I removed some unused `.csproj` projects from the `.sln` file and the build from `master` branch works, however when I switch to a remote branch the `dll` files from those unused and removed projects are still causing some issues.

When building the solution from a remote branch, I get the following errors:

[image]

I'm going crazy here. Below are the following things I have tried:

- Clean solution, exit VS, rebuild solution
- Start VS as administrator and rebuild
- Check and uncheck the properties for builds in the project settings

I'm using the most recent and updated version of Visual Studio

Comment: I think it's best to create a new project and copy the needed files to this new empty clean project.

Comment: Please check *.csproj files to see if they have any traces of thouse dlls.

Comment: @MikeMozhaev So the remote branch does in fact references to those files, but the projects actually exist in the remote branches too (I can see the folders locally when I'm on the remote branch), so it shouldn't really fail imo, right?

Comment: If you dont's have references to these dlls in the `csproj` files in the current solution, then it should not fail. But sometimes we might observe some weird behavior.

You should be able to see the step which fails and the corresponding details if you turn set `MSBuild project build output verbosity` to `Detailed` in `Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Build And Run`.

Comment: So this is really odd, but I ran the project in Rider and it built and ran successfully. I then ran it in VS afterwards, and was able to build it and run successfully. The remote branches had references to those projects in the .sln file, and those projects folders also existed locally, it just didn't have the assembly files. Once I ran it in Rider and then in VS, those assembly files were created. No clue how or why that worked.